# WPF MVVMLight RelayCommand not executing randomly

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have a button in a WPF application that is acting strange, some times it will work completely fine, other times it won't fire at all.

If the button don't work can i restart the App a few times and it will work randomly again. I have added a Debug breakpoint on the `CanScan = false;` and that break point is not triggered when the button dose not work.

When the button is broken is it broken from the start of the App, it is not something where it works the first time and then stops. When the button is working is it working fine no matter how many times i click it and run the RelayCommand.

View Model Code:
        public ICommand OnScanPage { get; set; }

```
    public ScannerViewModel(ScanningService scanningService, Action<int> processingAction)
    {
        this.processingAction = processingAction;
        this.scanningService = scanningService;

        Pages = new ObservableCollection<ScannerPageViewModel>();

        CanScan = true;

        OnScanPage = new RelayCommand(() => {
            try
            {
                CanScan = false;
                processingAction.Invoke(1);

                scanningService.ScanPage(img =>
                {
                    DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
                    {
                        CanScan = true;
                        processingAction.Invoke(-1);
                        Pages.Add(new ScannerPageViewModel(this, processingAction, img));
                    });
                });
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }
        });
    }
```

View Model Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DocumentScanner.Views.Scanner.ScannerUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DocumentScanner.Views.Scanner"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Scan page" IsEnabled="{Binding CanScan}" Command="{Binding OnScanPage}" />

        <ListView Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Image MaxWidth="200" Source="{Binding Image}" Grid.RowSpan="2" />

                            <Button Command="{Binding Rotate}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10">Rotate</Button>
                            <Button Command="{Binding Remove}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Padding="10">Remove</Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

the scanning service:

```
public void ScanPage(Action<BitmapImage> onImage)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            ImageProcesser.Push(onImage);

            var myDS = selectedSource;
            myDS.Open();

            myDS.Capabilities.CapAutoFeed.SetValue(BoolType.True);
            myDS.Capabilities.CapAutoScan.SetValue(BoolType.True);

            myDS.Enable(SourceEnableMode.NoUI, true, IntPtr.Zero);
            myDS.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exp.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

**Update:** 
I change my RelayCommand to my new ECommand (see below) as it is working every time now. I am leaving this question open as i must be doing something wrong with the RelayCommand.

```
   public class ECommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action a;

        public ECommand(Action a)
        {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            a.Invoke();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Can you pls show the declaration of the `CanScan` property?

Comment: `public bool CanScan { get; set; }` I am using https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: Strange, code looks fine to me.

Comment: I added the code to a separate ICommand implementation, and it works every time now. Leaving the question open in case i am using the RelayCommand incorrect.